# Как убрать отступы после заголовка и элементов в AlertDialog?

Tags: android, padding, android-alertdialog

На нижепреведённом скрине видны отступы после заголовков и элементов списка AlertDialog. Для наглядности диалоговое окно не кастомизировано.

Скажите, как избавиться от этих отступов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***UPD: Кода вызова диалога***

```
List<SocialItem> socials = new ArrayList<>();
addSocials(socials);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new SocialArrayAdapter(contextThis, R.layout.feedback_social_item, socials);
DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener =  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(socials.get(which).getSource())));
      }
};
dialog = getDialogBuilder("Напишите разработчикам", true, adapter, onClickListener, null).create();
dialog.show();
```

Код метода `getDialogBuilder()`

```
public AlertDialog.Builder getDialogBuilder(String title, boolean isCustomTitle, ArrayAdapter adapter,
                                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener, String bodyText) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextThis);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    if (title != null) {
        if (isCustomTitle) {
            View customTitle = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_social_title, null);
            ((TextView) customTitle).setText(title);
            adb.setCustomTitle(customTitle);
        } else {
            adb.setTitle(title);
        }
    }
    if (adapter != null && onClickListener != null) {
        adb.setAdapter(adapter, onClickListener);
    } else if (bodyText != null) {
        adb.setMessage(bodyText);
    }
    return adb;
}
```

Код метода `addSocials()`

```
private void addSocials(List<SocialItem> socials) {
    String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.feedback_socials);
    String[] sources = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.feedback_sources);
    socials.add(new SocialItem(titles[0], sources[0], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_vk_logo)));
    socials.add(new SocialItem(titles[1], sources[1], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_mail_logo)));
    socials.add(new SocialItem(titles[2], sources[2], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_tg_logo)));
    socials.add(new SocialItem(titles[3], sources[3], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_inst_logo)));
}
```

Код кастомного заголовка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customTitleAlert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingVertical="12dp"
    android:background="@color/my_sea"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>
```

Comment: прикрепите пожалуйста разметку вашего диалога, так гадать можно долго что это может быть.

Comment: @Andrew разметка дефолтная
Каким образом её можно прикрепить к посту?

Comment: вот смотрите - вы прикрепляете скрин и говорите что есть проблема) но никто не знает как вы его выводите) никто не видит контекста проблемы, я попросил разметку по ошибке, подумав что вы его все-таки как-то кастомизировали, если нет, то приложите хотя-бы код вывода диалога для начала, по картинке сложно сказать наверняка

Comment: стиль это ваш - R.style.custom_alert_dialog? если да то его тоже не помешает прикрепить

Comment: @Andrew изменил код. Стиль не указывал в примере на скрине

Comment: приложите пожалуйста R.layout.custom_alert_social_title?

Comment: @Andrew кастомный заголовок, но я делал и без такового, результат не поменялся - отступы так же есть

Comment: Первый вариант - копайте стиль диалога, особенно если наследуюте его от одного из системных или материальных. Второй вариант - это декоратор списка так написан, опять же нужно копать системный код алёрта)

Comment: @Nuclominus, есть и третий вариант - с учетом того что уже есть разметка для элемента списка, можно немного запариться и сделать свой dialog с разметкой, где соответственно убрать все отступы, потому что поиск по стилям может не принести желаемого результата )

Comment: @Andrew Можно. Можно и андроид переписать нормально, время было бы)

Comment: @Nuclominus, ну это было бы вообще неплохо)))))